# linked lists prints nothing

Tags: c, pointers

When I add values to the list, it prints nothing.

The switch statement in `main?  switches between input picked from the user to call the appropriate function.
Putting one will prompt you to add a number and when 2 is typed in, the list must be printed.

The problem is, it prints nothing even if I have inserted

> c

```
#include<stdlib.h>//header files
#include<stdio.h>

struct node{  //structure containing node
   int data;
   struct node *next;//next link
};

struct node *head = NULL;//head pointer

void print_list(struct node *ptr);//prints list
struct node *add_node( int d);//adds value to list
void push(struct node*m);//creates node

int main(){
    int status;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("****************menue oriented**********************\n");
        printf("Enter 1 for adding node, 2 for printing and rest for exiting\n");
        scanf("%d", &status);//switch statement for picking data

        switch(status)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("you selected the adding part\n");
            push(head);//1 adds item
            break;
        case 2:
            print_list(head);// 2 prints list
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong input boss\n");// default call
            break;
        exit(0);// program termination
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

struct node *add_node(int d)
{//add node function
    struct node *extra = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //node size allocation with malloc
    extra->data = d;//adds value d
    extra->next = NULL;//sets ponter to null

    return extra;//returns the pointer 
}

void print_list(struct node *ptr)
{
    struct node *x;//new pointer
    x = ptr;//pointer == head
    if(x == NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty boss\n");//executed if empty
        exit(0);
    }
    while(x->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("********************************************\n");
        printf("%d\n", x->data);//print data
        x = x->next;//move to next node
    }
}

void push(struct node*m)
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter value to add to lost\n");//enter value from console
    scanf("%d",&x);
    struct node *p;
    p = add_node(x);//store pointer in p
    if(m == NULL)
    {//let head point to p if head is empty
        m = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p->next = m;//pointer of p pointers to head and head points to p
        m = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugger is your closest friend in situation like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what gets passed into the push function is a copy of the pointer, not the pointer itself. That's why it cannot be replaced. It's like with values - what gets sent to the function is a copy of the value, not the real value so if you change it in the function it doesn't change outside of it. If you want to change the original value, you send a pointer of it to the function. It's the same with a pointer - want to overwrite the original pointer? - send in a pointer of that pointer.

You want to change these:

```
 void push(struct node**m); //take a pointer to a pointer
```

in main:

```
push(&head); //pass the address of head to the function
```

and your function:

```
void push(struct node**m){
    int x;
    printf("Enter value to add to lost\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    struct node *p;
    p = add_node(x);
    if(*m == NULL){ //de-reference the copied pointer to acquire the actual pointer
        *m = p; //same as above
    }
    else{
        p->next = *m; //same as above
        *m = p; //same as above
    }
    }
```

Second of all, your printing will stop if the 'next' item is NULL, but it won't display the tail's value. After the while loop, you should print the data one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your `push` function where you assign the new pointer to the function argument. C is pass by value so the head pointer is not changed at all. You can either pass a pointer to the head pointer (see other answer) or return the updated pointer an call it with `head = push(head);`

```
struct node* push(struct node*m){
int x;
printf("Enter value to add to lost\n");//enter value from console
scanf("%d",&x);
struct node *p;
p = add_node(x);//store pointer in p
if(m == NULL){//let head point to p if head is empty
    m = p;
}
else{
    p->next = m;//pointer of p pointers to head and head points to p
    m = p;
}
return m;
}
```